# Is there a way to force a parameter to be passed through as a dot-dot-dot parameter?

Tags: r

I have a function that I would like to call with a certain parameter as one of the dot-dot-dot paramets (`col`) unfortunately this function already has three named variables starting with `col` (`colNonSig`, `colSig`, and `colLine`) and so preferentially matches these:

[image: usage definition of the plotMa function from rdocumentation.org]

As the documentation above mentions, I would like to pass through `col` to the underlying call to `plot`.

Comment: It looks as though passing `col` through the dots wouldn't do anything here, since color is already handled by the existing parameters. What are you trying to do with the `col` parameter specifically?

Comment: Having said that, you could try ensuring you pass some value to the existing `colxxx` parameters so that they are all specifically named in your call. This should remove the ambiguity about `col` being passed to the dots argument.

Comment: Gotcha - I would like to specify the colours as a vector rather than use the logic provided by the library function. That said, I'm assuming the use of `col` by the authors of the library as a prefix was intentional as it does defeat the objective of the function somewhat!

Comment: I have tried that and it still preferentially matches them (and spits out a 'matched by multiple arguments' error). But that is definitely the direction I was heading!

Comment: 'Preferentially' should be viewed as 'partially' (in a regex kind of way) to help searching for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of the function `plotMA` can be found [here](https://github.com/Bioconductor/geneplotter/blob/32b976ac3506fb48d2f90d32ef1c5738f64a8da3/R/plotMA.R#L1) and in its second last line includes a call to base R `plot` that looks like this:

```r
   plot(object$mean, pmax(ylim[1], pmin(ylim[2], py)),
       log = log, pch = ifelse(py < ylim[1], 6, ifelse(py > ylim[2], 2, 16)),
       cex = cex, col = ifelse(object$sig, colSig, colNonSig), xlab = xlab, 
       ylab = ylab, ylim = ylim, ...)
```

You can see that internally, `plotMA` *already* uses the `col` parameter, by taking the `colNonSig` and `colSig` variables and using them to determine what color the points will be based on their significance level. This is why you get the error about matching multiple arguments. It is not that you are partially matching arguments with `plotMA`, but that you are passing two `col` arguments to base R's `plot` *inside* the `plotMA` function.

There is no direct way round this that will allow you to pass `col` directly to the function, but since you want to pass a vector of colors instead, you should get the same result by passing the vector of colors you wanted to pass to *both* `colSig` **and** `colNonSig`, since this will result in a copy of that vector being passed to `col` internally.

Your other option is to create your own copy of the function which just removes the `col = ifelse(object$sig, colSig, colNonSig),` in the above code, but that seems a bit pointless when the work-around is so easy.